# AngularJS: Unable to invoke controller from a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am a newbie with AngularJS/Ionic, and am facing a problem with the following piece of code:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicPopover, $state, $cordovaOauth){

//The following is used in the ng-click of a button
$scope.doAction = function () {
    $cordovaOauth.google("xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", ["email"]).then(function (result) {
        // results
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        $scope.google_access_token = result.access_token;

        var http = $http({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                access_token: result.access_token
            }
        });
        http.then(function (data) {
            var user_data = data.data;
            //The code is reaching here, as the alert is successfully shown with data 
            alert("Name: " + user_data.name + "\nEmail: " + user_data.email
                +"\nPicture:" + user_data.picture);
            userInfo.fullName = user_data.name;
            userInfo.userId = user_data.email;
            userInfo.img = user_data.picture;
            localStorage.setItem('loggedInUser', user_data.email);
            //But this is not taking me to the other controller 
            $state.go('tabsController.someOtherController');
        });

    }, function (error) {
        // error
        alert(error);
    });
  }

}
```

As I mentioned in the comments in the code, the execution reaches inside http.then but it is not invoking the other controller with $state.go. If I place it before doAction(), then it is getting invoked, which means there is nothing wrong with the controller itself. Can someone please help identify what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how do you define your routes on app.js. $state.go('tabsController.someOtherController'); will go to 'tabsController.someOtherContorller' state.

Comment: .state('tabsController.someOtherController', {
    url: '/someother',
    views: {
      'tab1': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/someOtherPage.html',
        controller: 'SomeOtherCtrl'
      }
    }

Comment: is this alert("Name: " + user_data.name + "\nEmail: " + user_data.email
                +"\nPicture:" + user_data.picture); displaying?

Comment: Yes, it is displaying fine.

Comment: When I debugged, I found that $state is undefined where it is calling $state.go

Comment: try to move $state.go right before comment //results. is the $state.go working?

Comment: @mtamma - It is not working :-(

Comment: did you test that on the simulator. because there is an important note about this libarary which is This library will NOT work with a web browser, ionic serve, ionic live-reload, or ionic view. It MUST be used via installing to a device or simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are **NOT** states. they are defined in the `run` clause in your `app.js` file.

For `$state.go` to work you need to specify a state **name** as defined in `run`.

Example:

For this declaration

```
.run(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $stateProvider
  .state('home', { ... })
  .state('main', { abstract: true, ... })
  .state('main.first', {
   controller: 'firstCtrl'
  })
  .state('main.second', {
   controller: 'secondCtrl'
  });
});
```

These are valid:

```
$state.go('home');
$state.go('main.first');
$state.go('main.second');
```

Comment: @muli-yulzari - I have that right already. Which is why if I place the $state.go call before making the cordovaOuth.google line, it works fine.